# Set line endings for all tabs and all open files

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, line-endings

Some of my files/tabs somehow got to be Unix line endings, when I want Windows line endings. I can go to view > line endings > windows, but that applies it only for the current file/tab opened. I don't want to have to do it for every file (which I did). But even if I do this, when I open other files, sometimes they are set in Unix. Is there a single setting that can apply it for all files, whether they are opened or unopened?

If I go to preferences > Settings - default > and go to the default_line_endings setting, its value is set to 'system'. I know i COULD override this in my 'Settings - User' setting, but I didn't have to do this before the line endings somehow got all messed up. Is there another way?

Also, If i reinstall sublimetext, would this fix it, or are the line endings somehow dependent on the files themselves? I imagine it would be sublime text that decides which line endings to use, perhaps based on what line endings are in the file. But I don't know this for sure. Plus, all my line endings used to be the windows's CRLF, not Unix's LF.

Controlling the line endings in sublime text is currently kind of a pain, since it has no en masse way to view or set, current files, nor an en masse way to set it for future files.

Any knowledge would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

The [Line​Endings](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LineEndings) plugin / package is small, but works like a charm  Visit it's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SublimeText/LineEndings#description) to get a few details, because on its Package Control page there is no description.

It not only works, but also gives you an additional functionality -- you can change not only line endings, but also indentation method of all open files in one step.

After installation:

1. Open all files, in which you want to convert / change line endings and/or indentation method.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, to bring Command Pallete and start typing `lin` to locate `Line Ending to all views: Windows` (for example).
3. Select it, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and... you're done!
4. Repeat step 2, but type `spaces` to locate `Indentation: Convert to all views to Spaces` or `tabs` to locate `Indentation: Convert to all views to Tabs` to change indentation method of all open files.

Note, that either this plugin has a bug or Sublime Text 3 gets sometimes a bit wako. Some searches did not reveal above mentioned commands. And I had to close and reopen Command Palette and type sequence again. Especially, if you have any kind of linter installed in ST3, its command may interfere with [Line​Endings](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LineEndings)'s commands, as you type `lin`.

Comment: Note, the `Line​Endings` plugin no longer seems to be available via Package Control (page says that it has been removed)

Answer (score 6):

There is a plugin that will do what you want [`sublime-line-endings-unify`](https://github.com/vontio/sublime-line-endings-unify).

The `default_line_endings` setting will only affect new files.  Sublime will use whatever line ending is already there for existing files.  Perhaps you have a tool (such as your source control system) that is changing the endings.  Sublime itself will not change them unless you explicitly change it.